# Swap out DOM elements with JavaScript, for memory intensive application

Tags: javascript, html, dom, memory

I want to be sure that I do not run into any memory problems in the following scenario.

I am preparing to create an application that will use many different interactive screens. There will be a number of global objects that need to be maintained from screen to screen. This implies using a single page for the entire application. Each screen contains high-resolution images and many interactive controls.

When displaying a new screen, I want to be sure that images from the previous screen are removed from the RAM. This implies removing them from the DOM and deleting any JavaScript references to them.

I have come up with the following technique:
* Each screen is represented by a different JS file.
* Each JS file contains a constructor: Screen1(), Screen2() and so on.
* The resulting object has a method which returns an HTML string. It may also have a method which returns a url for a custom css file.
* To jump to a new screen, a Swap object destroys the current Screen object, and replaces it with a new object created by the appropriate constructor.
* The Swap object then sets the innerHTML of the body of the page. It may also swap in a custom css file for the current screen.
* The Swap object then calls a start() method in the current Screen object, to initialize all the interactivity.

jsFiddle is not happy to simulate this, so I have created two links for you to test this:
demo: http://openbook.lexogram.com/proto/swap/
source: http://openbook.lexogram.com/proto/swap.zip

My questions:
1. Are there any obvious flaws in this approach?
2. Has this issue already been resolved using a more conventional approach?

Here's an extract of the code to give you an idea of how it works:

```
// SWAP OBJECT //

function Swap(container, constructor) {
  this.container = container
  this.in(constructor)
}

Swap.prototype.in = function screen(constructor) {
  if (this.screen) {
    this.kill(this.screen)
    delete this.screen
  }

  this.screen = new constructor()
  this.container.innerHTML = this.screen.html()
  this.screen.start()
}

Swap.prototype.kill = function kill(object) {
  for (key in object) {
    delete this[key]
  }
}


var swap
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
  swap = new Swap(body, Screen1)
  swap.in(Screen1)
});




// SCREEN1 (in a different js file) //

function Screen1() {}

Screen1.prototype.html = function getHTML() {
  return "<div id='screen1'>"+
    "<p>Click anywhere to go to Screen 2</p>"+
  "</div>"
}

Screen1.prototype.start = function startScreen1() {
  this.link = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]

  this.link.onclick = function showScreen2(event) {
    swap.in(Screen2)
  }
}


// SCREEN2 not shown, but similar
```

Comment: You don't have the level of control you think you have. The OS, browser, and underlining software control memory usage, not you. All you can do it unset references using `delete` and hope the browser handles things the way you want it to.

Comment: Sure. I understand that. I want to make sure that the approach I adopt does not hinder the browser from cleaning up as best it can. And yes, my Swap object uses `delete` to kill references.

Comment: Then that's really all you can do. After that it's up to the Browser and OS to release the resources correctly and not have memory leaks.

Comment: Are you suggesting that my method is overkill? Is there an easier, better documented way to handling a single page with many many high resolution images that I have overlooked?

Comment: I'm saying if you are successfully using delete, then you've reached the end. Once you've deleted it, there is really no more to do. I would suggest in your case using as few libraries as possible though to lower overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the most interesting and also dangarous part of your code is the `start` method. Without it, it looks good, except the `kill` function - it is like shooting in a dark room) You overwrite your `this.screen` property anyway, so the old reference should be then deleted, in case you have no memory leaks in your `start` method.

So all your `interactivity` is risky. This could be some jQuery widgets or some other things, that hold references to the nodes, and so they wont be removed from the memory by the garbage collector. This could be even raw event listeners, or some enclosed closures with the DOM node references. But you have a good weapon in your arsenal - [Memory Timeline](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline), [Heap Profiler](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling). The process is simple: open your first screen → collect stats of the memory allocation → go to next screen → enforce garbage collector → measure and compare memory.